# Printing a hash in C

Tags: c, hash, hex, byte, sha256

I am trying to print a SHA256 hash in C but when I use the for loop shown below, the only way the hash is printed is when I add the newline to printf. Ideally I want to print it all on one line.

```
void enclave_main()
{
    char string[] = "Hello World";
    int x;

    unsigned char digest[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    SHA256_Update(&sha256, string, strlen(string));
    SHA256_Final(digest, &sha256);

    for(x = 0; x < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; x++)
        printf("%02x\n", digest[x]);

    sgx_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdout);`?

Comment: Print the newline only after the last byte, not after each.  Or flush the output stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard output is (typically) line-buffered, which means output won't be flushed to the terminal until the buffer is full *or* you send a newline *or* you flush the stream manually with `fflush()`.

The easiest thing to do is print the newline after the loop:

```
for(x = 0; x < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; x++)
        printf("%02x", digest[x]);
putchar( '\n' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works when I use fflush(). Printing the newline after the for loop didn't work. It just prints a new line without the hash. Mind you I am doing this in an emulator, so maybe there lies the problem.